# How do I make the ScrollView scroll behind the keyboard?

Tags: android

I have a screen with a lot of text and an EditText field.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@color/blue_dark_grey">

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputFl"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/backTv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/radikal"
                    android:text="@string/back"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <com.weare8.android.ui.widgets.TextViewBoldWhite
                    android:id="@+id/loginPasswordTitle"
                    style="@style/OnBoardingTitleTextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"
                    android:text="@string/log_in_password_title"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/forgotPasswordTv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/log_in_password_reset"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Text.RadikalBold.White"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </ScrollView>


    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputFl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nextTv"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordEt"
                style="@style/OnBoardingInputEditTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/log_in_enter_a_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/passwordModeIv"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/selector_eye"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nextTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/onboarding_button_blue"
            android:fontFamily="@font/radikal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:text="@string/on_boarding_next_action"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

The dark blue area (Scrollview), the password field, and the next button are stacked on top of each other in a LinearLayout. When the soft keyboard is open, it covers the contents of the ScrollView without adjusting their position, and they cannot be seen or scrolled to.

[image]

I would like to make it so that the section of the ScrollView that gets covered by the keyboard can be scrolled to when the keyboard is up, currently it stays hidden and locked in place. How do I make it react to the presence of the soft keyboard?

Comment: Did you try to add this line to your manifest    
 `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>`

Comment: Yes, that's what my manifest has.